# How to compute area under ROC curve from predicted class probabilities, in R using pROC or ROCR package?

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, auc

I have used caret library to compute class probabilities and predictions for a binary classification problem, using 10-fold cross validation and 5 times repetition.

Now I have **TRUE** (observed values for each data point) values, **PREDICTED** (by an algorithm) values, **Class 0 probabilities** and **Class 1 probabilities** which were used by an algorithm to predict class label.

Now how can I create an `roc` object using either `ROCR` or `pROC` library and then calculate `auc` value?

Assume that I have all these values stored in `predictions` dataframe. e.g. `predictions$pred` and `predictions$obs` are the predicted and true values respectively, and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you did not provide a reproducible example, I'm assuming you have a binary classification problem and you predict on `Class` that are either `Good` or `Bad`.

```
predictions <- predict(object=model, test[,predictors], type='prob')
```

You can do:

```
> pROC::roc(ifelse(test[,"Class"] == "Good", 1, 0), predictions[[2]])$auc
# Area under the curve: 0.8905
```